# Meaning of 'should have+p.p '

Tags: meaning

What is the meaning of 'should have ' in the following sentences do they mean regret or what ?

1.I should have let her know what was happening but I forgot.

2.They should have remembered that their guests don't eat meat meat.

3.I should have sent everybody a reminded by email.

4.He should have told them the truth but he didn't.

5.I don't think you should have done i
t.

I'm confused here because I know that'should have'is used to imply'regret' ,for example:

1.I got really wet today while going to market . I should have taken an umrella.

2.she wept so badly. I shouldn't have scolded her.

Comment: It just means that something did not happen how the speaker thinks it would have happened if everything went right.

Comment: I don't know that post , I'm different Op

Comment: I found it from your profile page.  It doesn't really matter, though.  It's still a duplicate.

Comment: Oh, it's my type mistake, i didn't mean to post the same question. What can i do know ? You said it doesn't matter why?

Comment: There should be a banner at the top that tells you someone voted to close it as a duplicate.  You can click the button that accepts it.  If you already declined, you can flag the question as a duplicate.  The banner will then appear.  My point was that it doesn't matter who asked.  One question is a duplicate of another if it is asking the same thing.

Answer (score 1):

Besides implying regret for something that was or wasn't done, "should have" can also be used:

1. To talk about past events that did not happen:

> He should have told them the truth but he didn't.

2. To speculate about events that may or may not have happened:

> They should have got the letter this morning. I expect they will let
>   us know about it later.

3. To speculate *negatively* about what may or may not have happened:

> He shouldn't have left work yet. I'll call him at the office.

4. To tell other people that a different action in the past would have been better:

> You should have helped him instead of just looking on.

As for the five example sentences, my opinion is that ## 1, 4 may be regarded as both regrets and just statements, depending on the context; # 5 is an opinion about what would have been better; # 3 is a regret, and # 2 is either a reproach  for something that wasn't done (also a regret) or a speculation about what may have been done - again, depending on the context.

Comment: Rompey@ what about my all 5 examples ? Please also address or include them to your answer ? Are they all regreats?

Comment: yubraj sharma@ Added a paragraph. Sorry, I should have done it earlier.

Comment: Do you mean "Should have+p.p" also means sth important thing that we missed or didn't do so it's regreat

Comment: If the undone action doesn't result in anything important, what is it to be woth regretting?

Comment: I also want to request you to migrate this answer to previous question as it's a duplicate of previous. Sorry, it's duplicate because of mistake, I shouldn't have misstyped